# Inside and outside function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

This code is letting me input a string, and that string is added to the dict 'd'. However I want to use this functionality in a gui but when used with the gui I am missing something. Because it won´t work.

This first code works as intended (being outside a function)(Print statements are there just for the testing purpose.):

```
d = {"username": "XYZ", "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "location":"Mumbai"}

r=str(input())
d[r] =' '

print(r)
print(d)
```

While this code below does not work as intended. When I run the code it just idles. Why?
How do I fix this global/local issue (just my guess)?

```
def newSite():
    print('opening dialogue')
    r = str(input())
    
    d[r] =' '
```

The function is called in a button.

```
Button(root, height=1, width=10, text=" <- Input site!  ", command=newSite).grid(row=6, column=3, sticky=W, pady=10)
```

Comment: You posted your working code but forgot to post the non-working one.

Comment: Yes because I was still working on this question when you answered.

Comment: Don't use console `input()` in a GUI application.  Use `simpledialog.askstring()` instead.

Comment: I use tk.Entry and not simple dialogue tho but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to call console `input()` in a GUI application, use `simpledialog.askstring()` instead:

```py
from tkinter import simpledialog
...

def newSite():
    print("opening dialogue")
    r = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "Enter Site")
    if r and r.strip():
        d[r.strip()] = " "
    print(d)

...
```

Answer (score -1):

I presume that when you say idl you mean you run it and it does not do anything.

Your second set of code contains a function, but that's it. Namely you're not calling it via: `newSite()` after it's defined.

Comment: I am doing that somewhere else.   Button(root, height=1, width=10, text=" <- Input site!  ", command=newSite).grid(row=6, column=3, sticky=W, pady=10)

Comment: Ah, well it's helpful to see the full code of how you're calling it. See the below answer about GUI and `input()`.

Comment: Yes I should have included that from the start ofcourse.